# change fonts of applications in dwm

Tags: x11, fonts, dwm

I'm currently using dwm 6.0 and I was wondering how I could change the font of programs like  Firefox. I already changed the font given in the config.h and recompiled it but it didn't change anything.
Am I right that I can't change the font of the terminal within the config.h
?

Answer (score 4):

Each application chooses its own fonts. The window manager only chooses the fonts of the text that it displays, such as window title bars and its own menus.

Firefox uses [Gtk settings](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GTK%2B) to determine the appearance of its menus, dialog boxes and other user interface elements. To [control the rendering of web pages](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-fonts-and-colors-websites-use), change the “Preferences → Content” settings, or for more control, [set custom CSS](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/unix/customizing.html) (either via `userContent.css` or via an extension).

To change the font of the terminal, change the settings of whatever terminal emulator you are using.

Comment: So the font of the eg firefox buttons are controlled by the gtk settings? I can change them, right? But the webpages do show the exact same font as used by dwm and they don't differ from each other